# Unpickled object does not match original

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, pickle

My program fails to unpickle my data, where pickle.load(f) does not match pickle.dump(object,f).
My question is where am I going wrong with the following code, as I have experimented with various
file modes with the corresponding errors listed above my code below:

**f = open(home + '/.GMouseCfg','ab+')**

*out: They are different*

**f = open(home + '/.GMouseCfg','ab+', encoding='utf-8')**

*ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument*

**f = open(home + '/.GMouseCfg','a+')**

*TypeError: must be str, not bytes*

```
import abc, pprint
from evdev import ecodes as e
from os.path import expanduser

try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except:
    import pickle


class Command(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def set(self, data):
        """set data used by individual commands"""
        return

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def run(self):
        """implement own method of executing data of said command"""
        return

class KeyCommand(Command):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def set(data):
        self.data = data
    def run(self):
        pass
    def __str__(self):
        return data

class SystemCommand(Command):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def set(data):
        self.data = data
    def run(self):
        pass
    def __str__(self):
        return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ids = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
    home = expanduser('~')
    f = open(home + '/.GMouseCfg','a+')
    f.seek(0)

    commands = list()
    commands.append(KeyCommand({3:[e.KEY_RIGHTCTRL,e.KEY_P]}))
    commands.append(SystemCommand({5:['gedit','./helloworld.txt']}))
    pickle.dump(commands,f)
    f.seek(0)
    commands2 = pickle.load(f)
    if commands == commands2:
        print('They are the same')
    else:
        print('They are different')
```

I have done alot of reading on python docs for pickles and file io but am unable to discern why there is a difference between my original object and the unpickled one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After pickling and unpickling, obviously `command` and `command2` will never be the same object.

That means `commands == commands2` will always return `False`, unless you implement [comparision](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) for your class, for example:

```
class KeyCommand(Command):
    ...
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.data == other.data
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self.data != other.data
    ...

class SystemCommand(Command):
    ...
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.data == other.data
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self.data != other.data
    ...
```

Comment: This solved the problem.  My deepest apologies, I did not realize that the eq operator would need to be overloaded to check for equality.  So then do both commands and commands2 have the same data and structure, and do I even need to test this. I started learning python a few weeks ago but it should have clicked because I overloaded equals operators back in c++ and c#